# Double hop marshaling in COM

Tags: winapi, com, marshalling, win32-process

Consider the following.

- Process A is a COM client. It creates an object in process B
- The object has a method that returns an interface pointer
- The implementation in B creates an object in process C and returns that to A

After this, will calls from A to C go through B? If the process B quits, will the object proxy in A error on method calls?

Comment: COM keeps references through the AddRef/Release methods of IUnknown. As long as they are correctly called/paired, you will not get any errors

Comment: This is not about ref counting, this is about cross process marshaling. If implemented naively, the interface pointer in B will be marshaled to A as if it was an object in B, won't it? Meanwhile, it's but a proxy to an object in C.

Comment: It is probably short-circuited at the RPC channel level.  Hard to be sure, unspecified in the docs and you'd have to be *really* courageous to contemplate such a brittle architecture.  Just try it.

Comment: yes, in B will be created proxy to real object in C. and in A will be proxy to B proxy. so every call will be double marshaled. of course if not use special custom marshalling

Comment: possible after A got (double) proxy to C - it called some it special method and got direct proxy for self. without B proxy

Comment: or use special implementation - via some method direct ask C for mashal data to stream and pass this stream to A process (without unmarshal it in B). and unmarshal data just in A

Comment: You said "If the process B quits, will the object proxy in A error on method calls?" no, if ref count is ok.  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/098759899/CHP21CHP.HTM 22.2.4

Comment: IIRC, if a process with a live proxy quits, the ref count in the out of process server *is* decreased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested. As of Windows 10 19044, COM short circuits the double hop. Killing B doesn't break the channel.

[Here are the samples.](https://gist.github.com/sevaa/6c54b79be096fff6ea7beed37d7ab849) Build a.cpp, b.cpp, and c.cpp as three separate Windows GUI apps in Visual Studio. Run B and C in either order, then A. The A program has some UI to drive the test.